# How to hide a file input item in a form?

Tags: javascript, file, input

I'm developing a web page that lets user upload a font file, but the requirement is to display the font name after user selects a file, then he can decide to upload it or not, the font name is a property in the font file, the file name might be "123.ttf", but when you right click on the font file and look into it "Title" preperty, it's called "ACME Explosive Bold", so my Javascript should ideally find the "tilte" property of this font, but after lots of research, I was told JS can't get this property, while on the other hand I've found a piece of Java code that can get it.

So now I'm trying to hide a 2nd form on the page, with an input field whose value will be the user selected file from the first form, when user selected a file but before he clicks the first form's submit button, my JS calls the 2nd form with user selected file, submit it and run a servlet to find it's "Title" and come back and display it on the page, then delete that file on the server, because user has never officially submitted it.

So my question is how to hide this 2nd form with it's own input file field and browse button on the page, I need the form tag so I can simulate a submit. But I don't want users to see it ?

Here is my code so far :

```
![<div class="body">
    <h1>Upload Font</h1>                                                       <%-- \[+\] --%>
    <s:form namespace="/font" action="add" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="dialog">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="form" />
                    <tr class="prop">
                        <td valign="top" class="name required">
                            <label for="description">Font File:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <s:file name="file" size="62" theme="simple" id="fname" onchange="fileUpload('/pages/font/getFontTitle.jsp',value,this.files\[0\])"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr class="prop">
                        <td>
                            <span class="button"><s:submit/></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div> 
    </s:form>
    <s:form namespace="/font" action="hiddenForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="dialog">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="prop">
                        <td valign="top">
                            <s:file name="file" size="62" theme="simple" id="fname_1"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div> 
    </s:form>
</div>]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the second form using CSS property visibility : hidden.

```
<s:form namespace="/font" style ='visibility:hidden' action="hiddenForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Use `display: none` rather than `visibility: hidden` so it doesn't take up space on the page.